# BASH converting txt to csv

Tags: bash, sed, csv

BASH/scripting newbie here.

```
sed 's/ \+/,/g' output3.txt > output.csv
```

This one gave me so many delimited.
I only one to delimit the "pipe" | symbol and leave the rest as it is. So basically, there'll be only two columns in the csv output file.

CSV file Input:

```
   google.com | companycode-12345
```

When I applied this line sed 's/ +/,/g' output3.txt > output.csv the results is:

```
  google.com | companycode  - 12345
```

What I'm looking is the following:

```
 google.com | companycode-12345
```

Comment: Can you share a line from the input where the behaviour can be demonstrated?

Comment: thanks for replying.

line in the text file
=============
https://www.google.com   | companycode-12345

when applied this line sed 's/ \+/,/g' output3.txt > output.csv the results is:
https://www.google.com(spaced) | (spaced) companycode (spaced) - (spaced) 12345

What I'm looking is the following:
https://www.google.com(spaced) | (spaced) companycode-12345

Comment: @PrakashSundra Welcome to SU.  You should comments with important information (like the above) into the question - this makes it easier to read (and in this case you can use code blocks to make it even easier)

Comment: I've edited tge post with your comment. please check if its correct - what you wrote is a bit confusing. Specifically  did you mean for the | to be replaced with a comma?

Comment: Does that input really give you that output?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `sed 's/ | /,/g'` ?

Comment: hi @davidgo noted on it and will post it accordingly the next time around.

Comment: hi @harrymc, that did the job! thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved with:

```
sed 's/ | /,/g'
```